# Why doesn't my continue execute the next when block in Perl 5.10?

Tags: perl, switch-statement, continue

When I run this:

```
use feature ':5.10';
$x=1;
given ($x) {
    when(1) {
        say '1';
        $x = 2;
        continue;
    }
    when (2) {
        say '2';
    }
}
```

This should print both 1 and 2, but it only prints 1.  Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I have added $x = 2 and it still prints only "1"

Comment: Why do you expect it to output 2? `$x` is 1.

Comment: see my edit... still not working

Comment: that won't work because the `given` copies `$x` to `$_`, which is the parameter to the smart match. If you set `$_ = 2` in the first `when`, it will work.

Comment: FWIW, I show an extended example in _Learning Perl, Fifth Edition_ that goes through this problem. :)

Comment: Also, to anyone playing at home, use 5.10.1. Smart matching is broken in 5.10.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) man page:

> given(EXPR)  will assign the value of EXPR to $_ within the lexical scope of the block

This code outputs 1 and 2:

```
use feature ':5.10';
$x=1;
given ($x) {
    when(1) {
        say '1';
        $_ = 2;
        continue;
    }
    when (2) {
        say '2';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of `continue` or the nature of fallthrough in a switch construct.

Every `when` block ends with an implicit break, so the `given` is exited upon a successful match. All `continue` does is tell the `given` block to continue processing the `when` conditions and not break out. It doesn't force the next `when` condition to magically be true when it isn't.

Consider this, which *does* output twice.

```
use feature ':5.10';
$x=1;
given ($x) {
    when(1) {
        say '1';
        continue;
    }
    when ( /1/ ) {
        say '1 again';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the source of my misunderstanding was C, where fall-through in "switch" does not do any additional testing... it just falls through and executes the next block.

Answer (score 0):

Since given is not a loop construct (despite it supporting continue, which is special cased in that instance), use foreach or for like so:

```
use feature ':5.10';
$x=1;
for ($x) {
    when(1) {
        say '1';
        $x = 2;
        continue;
    }
    when (2) {
        say '2';
    }
}
```

for (expression) sets $_ to the expression, and that behaviour was used to emulate switch in some cases, before given/when.